# List comprehension with mix of for-loops and if-conditions

Tags: python, list-comprehension

So I have the following piece of code from my reddit bot:

```
for sorting in self.possible_sortings:
    if self.sorting_flags[sorting]:
        if self.sorting_timeframe_possible_flag[sorting]:
            for timeframe in self.possible_timeframes:
                if self.timeframe_flags[timeframe]:
                    self.array_out.append([subreddit_name, sorting, timeframe, ammount_posts])
        else:
            self.array_out.append([subreddit_name, sorting, None, ammount_posts])
```

and I want to turn it into a comprehension. As to why, it should be slightly faster like that and also I want to practice it especially for nested stuff like this.

What I got so far is:

```
self.array_out += [
[subreddit_name, sorting, timeframe, ammount_posts] 
for timeframe in self.possible_timeframes 
if self.timeframe_flags[timeframe] 
if self.sorting_timeframe_possible_flag[sorting] else
[subreddit_name, sorting, None, ammount_posts] 
for sorting in self.possible_sortings 
if self.sorting_flags[sorting]
]
```

but after the `else` part it breaks. Is there a possibility to do it as a comprehension? Or is that just impossible for this kind of nested code?

Comment: But don't forget that readability counts...

Comment: Will the list comprehension add any benefit in this particular scenario? Is not the first code block more readable than the second code block?

Comment: I'm pretty sure list-comprehensions on their own can't accomplish what you want, but have never tried to do something as complex as that. Maybe refactoring the conditionals into a function?

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong, but are comprehensions actually faster that walking down conditions? I was under the impression it was equally efficient, and comprehensions should be used to enhance readability (which, I would argue this would not)

Comment: @chemicalwill the only difference is the `append`, which will keep copying the list of pointers every once in a while when the list gets bigger (like how C++ vector expands), otherwise the for/if has the same performance as the comprehension version.

Comment: @AhmedAEK thank you! in this example above, would it then be equally efficient to use `+= [put, values, here]`  rather than `append`?

Comment: @chemicalwill `+=` calls `extend` under the hood, so it's as efficient as `append` with slightly less copying, i'd say a better method is to chain generators and generator expression to delay the list creation, until you have an estimate of the final size.

Comment: @AhmedurRahmanShovon oh I absolutely will not use the less readable block. I am just practicing to use more comprehensions, and I kind of wanna know if its possible to do it with such complex stuff.

Comment: @chemicalwill Its mainly about only calling that part once. With the new solution I get a list added to the existing list, which is one operation. However, with append I just call append each iteration. 
In this case it is unimportant, but this can be seen as a question about how it works in general, in case I want to use it in a more serious application at some point. I do numerical maths stuff as well, and there its a very important factor. Here? Not so much. Normally you use comprehensions to leave the list generation to the interpreter.